# Running all tests with Rails / Spork / TestUnit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit, spork

The docs [here](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork-testunit/) say:

> Then, once spork is running, invoke testdrb (e.g. testdrb -Itest
>   test/your_test.rb) to run your tests under Spork.

But this only runs one at a time

Without specifying a file it fails:

```
$ testdrb
Exception encountered: #<SystemExit: exit>
```

I've found I can do this which helps a bit:

```
testdrb -I test test/functional/*
```

But still don't know how to run them all with one simple command the way I could with

```
rake test
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually write this *for all tests* :

```
testdrb -I test ./test/**/*_test.rb
```

To make things simple, I add this to my `.bashrc`

```
alias td="testdrb -I test"
alias tdall="testdrb -I test ./test/**/*_test.rb"
```

Comment: Updated. Also Ashville rocks.

Comment: running this command will only go into the directories right under test. I have a structure similar to this... test/unit (with some tests in here) and test/unit/lib (with more test in here). Is there a command that will allow me to look through all directories (regardless of depth) for files with "_test.rb"?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```
testdrb -I test $(ls test/**/*_test.rb)
```

**Edit**

Actually this is better:

```
testdrb -I test test/**/*_test.rb
```

Comment: That didn't work for me, I used: ```testdrb test/**/*_test.rb```